# string tripping - Additional information: Sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, visual-studio-debugging

I have a weird bug im running into.

I am getting: `Additional information: Sequence contains no elements` and its being tripped on `string sheetNum = "";`

I usually get this error when a ling function can't find anything so I am completely lost on why this is getting tripped off here.

Also, not sure if this is a result of my updating my Visual Studio IDE recently.

here is the code block that its in. its a button for winforms:

```
private void createSheetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sheetNum = ""; // <--- getting error here
            bool sheetNumExistsBool = false;
            if (colSheetsList.Count() > 0)
            {
                sheetNum = colSheetsList.First().get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.SHEET_NUMBER).AsString(); 
                sheetNumExistsBool = colSheetsList.Any(x => x.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.SHEET_NUMBER).AsString() == sheetNumTextBox.Text);
            }
            //... more code here 
       }
```

[image]

Comment: I would treat the debugger output as a 'Heisenbug' -- in other words: assume that the debugger is close but incorrect as to which line-of-code it is 'flagging' as the culprit.  Then I would temporarily revise the use of `First()` to `FirstOrDefault()` to try to get some additional symptom information.

Comment: @DavidTansey,  I will give that a shot. Any idea on how to solve the "Heisenbug" part and how to get the bug to fire off on the correct line? This doesn't seem like normal VS behavior. Usually, it's pretty spot-on in terms of showing which line is causing the error.

Comment: Which type has `colSheetsList`. Do you change it from other threads?

Comment: Are you debugging in Debug or Release mode? Release mode optimizations can make error locations problematic. The exception is definitely one that `First` would throw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that if the `colSheetsList` catch the `0` line, the rest of the code will continue to handle `0` line which is not suitable for it and will cause such error. You should add a non-zero operation.

You should use `FirstOrDefault()` as **Cflux** said instead. When it catch `0` line, it will break the rest of the code and return `null` to prevent such error.

**Solution**

Use `FirstOrDefault()`